# Return inserted rows in specified order for Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to return the rows from a table-valued insert in the same order they were specified.

I can use `OUTPUT INTO`

```
DECLARE @generated1 TABLE ([Id] varbinary(8), [OwnerId] [int]);

INSERT INTO [Blog] ([OwnerId])
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
INTO @generated1
VALUES ('1'),
('2'),
('1'),
('2'),
('2'),
('3'),
('3'),
('3'),
('3');

SELECT * FROM @generated1;
```

This usually works and returns

```
Id                  OwnerId
===========================
0x418B6EC7C6AC864D  1
0x6D0B89E56AB3EC48  2
0xE1B86C6A3C64AB42  1
0x51B8D9D1FCDE1647  2
0xB5AD578020CBCE4C  2
0x56CD3FF610080841  3
0x1D0D5B370A732C43  3
0x0B71CDB5CE6E0445  3
0x6A8AE3A2BD19924E  3
```

But if there is an FK defined on OwnerId and more than 125 rows are inserted the order in which they are inserted is different from the specified order.

Comment: Add an IDENTITY column to @generated1.

Comment: IDENTITY column in @generated1 doesn't help because the order the rows are inserted to `Blog` can be different from specified.

Comment: Do you have documentation of this?   I suppose it's possible, but it would surprise me.  If you used one `INSERT..VALUES..` for each row, then you would definitely be able to rely on the IDENTITY column.

Comment: I tried it and got the wrong order with the conditions specified above. "There is no guarantee that the order in which the changes are applied to the table and the order in which the rows are inserted into the output table or table variable will correspond." (source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).

Comment: If you wish to get values out of @generated1 in a specific order, you must specify it by `order by` in the select from @generated1. What column are you using to specify order?

Comment: Indeed I could split put each insertion to a separate statement, but this significantly decreases performance for large number of inserted rows.

Comment: @Brian Stork - I want the rows to be returned in the same order as specified in `VALUES`, there is no existing column that could provide this order

Comment: Tables do not have an order. Records on a table do not have an order. Tables are unsorted. When you select, the rows are returned in an arbitrary order unless you specify one. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568352/are-database-tables-sorted-before-or-after-being-retrieved

Comment: @Brian Stork I understand that. The question is how can I introduce the desired order without altering the schema or decreasing performance significantly.

Comment: You can't. You cannot guarantee the order rows are returned without specifying an `order by` column(s). If you don't specify those columns, the order is arbitrary.

Comment: @Brian Stork It's possible, see my answer below. But I am not sure that is the most efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way this could be accomplished is by adding a sequential value to each row to be inserted, joining the `generated` table with the values that were specified and ordering by the added sequential value:

```
DECLARE @inserted1 TABLE ([Order] [int], [OwnerId] [int]);
INSERT INTO @inserted1
VALUES ('1', '1'),
('2', '2'),
('3', '1'),
('4', '3'),
('5', '2'),
('6', '3'),
('7', '3'),
('8', '2'),
('9', '3');

DECLARE @generated1 TABLE ([Id] varbinary(8), [OwnerId] [int]);
INSERT INTO [Blog] ([OwnerId])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], INSERTED.[OwnerId]
INTO @generated1
SELECT [OwnerId] FROM @inserted1;

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT [g].[Id], [g].[OwnerId], [i].[Order]
FROM @generated1 [g]
INNER JOIN @inserted1 [i]
ON [g].[OwnerId] = [i].[OwnerId]) t
ORDER BY [Order];
```

But since `OwnerId` is non-unique this will produce more rows than inserted:

```
Id                  OwnerId Order
0x2557DCF354F9CD4E  1       1
0x3A265F70A2018249  1       1
0xA21503CD2F928144  2       2
0xE8C593480FCEAF41  2       2
0xC3E3C969BEA87641  2       2
0x2557DCF354F9CD4E  1       3
0x3A265F70A2018249  1       3
0x3F7EBD8EE702B44B  3       4
0xA3F09A3A612ACF41  3       4
0xA45D8F6FF779A74C  3       4
0x7BA9521290232D43  3       4
0xA21503CD2F928144  2       5
0xE8C593480FCEAF41  2       5
0xC3E3C969BEA87641  2       5
0x3F7EBD8EE702B44B  3       6
0xA3F09A3A612ACF41  3       6
0xA45D8F6FF779A74C  3       6
0x7BA9521290232D43  3       6
0x3F7EBD8EE702B44B  3       7
0xA3F09A3A612ACF41  3       7
0xA45D8F6FF779A74C  3       7
0x7BA9521290232D43  3       7
0xA21503CD2F928144  2       8
0xE8C593480FCEAF41  2       8
0xC3E3C969BEA87641  2       8
0x3F7EBD8EE702B44B  3       9
0xA3F09A3A612ACF41  3       9
0xA45D8F6FF779A74C  3       9
0x7BA9521290232D43  3       9
```

There are still only 9 unique values in `Id` and `Order` columns, the way they are combined shouldn't matter however, since the only value that identifies the row is `OwnerId`. The trick is to remove the rows from the result in a way that only 9 rows are returned with values in `Id` and `Order` being unique. Partitioning on both of the columns provides a way to deterministically order the combinations:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT [g].[Id], [g].[OwnerId], [i].[Order],
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [g].[Id] ORDER BY [i].[Order]) AS RowNumber,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [i].[Order] ORDER BY [g].[Id]) AS RowNumber2
FROM @generated1 [g]
INNER JOIN @inserted1 [i]
ON [g].[OwnerId] = [i].[OwnerId]) t
WHERE RowNumber = RowNumber2
ORDER BY [Order];
```

This returns the rows in the expected order:

```
Id                  OwnerId Order   RowNumber   RowNumber2
======================================================
0x2A51E4E35D2FA040  1       1       1           1
0x787E303904EC764C  2       2       1           1
0x778CE142E9760248  1       3       2           2
0xC056C57F1729E643  3       4       1           1
0xC0706FF6A8890E40  2       5       2           2
0x0E2058F3F142DF42  3       6       2           2
0x4690B24BE196374B  3       7       3           3
0x9F70CA6011ECD449  2       8       3           3
0xF35D87D1BDB2C34F  3       9       4           4
```