# MySQL predicate pushing

Tags: mysql, view, indexing

Is there any way to force MySQL to push a predicate into a view?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE VIEW v1
AS SELECT * FROM t1;
```

The query below will not use PRIMARY KEY index in MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM v1
WHERE id = 1
```

Instead it will select everything from t1, create a derived table and then filter it out for id = 1.

Is there any way to overcome this?

*PS: my real life example is a little bit more complex than the one above, but for simplicity I used the example above*

*PPS: here's a related Stack Overflow question: [How do I get MySQL to use an INDEX for view query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944946/how-do-i-get-mysql-to-use-an-index-for-view-query)*

Comment: It also does not seem to be supported for subqueries.

Comment: The Entity Framework (MSVS 2014) generates queries where the from clause is actually a subquery and predicate pushing does not happen for this form:  select * from (select * from someView) sv where x = x;

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you'd have to switch to the fully-compatible MariaDB 10.2.2

This is on by default and can be switched off using `optimizer_switch`:

```
SET GLOBAL optimizer_switch='condition_pushdown_for_derived=off'
```