# SQL - GROUP BY query optimization

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I am having some troubles trying to optimize the definition of a view in my db.

The query sums 2 kind of quantities based on `LEFT JOIN` of 3 tables, described as the `stocking` view within this fiddle: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83d1029/1/0)

Basically I tried to create indexes or re-define the view, but every time the execution time is ~5.5s even if the larges of the tables - *the `rows` table in the fiddle* - has ~15K records.

The thing that I'm struggling to understand is why, even if an index is defined for the `GROUP BY` column statement - shown in the possible_keys result for the `EXPLAIN` command - no index is used.

**--- EDIT ---**

I think that I've found my issue, the use of `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` on the `head` table and the `rows` table was slowing the query down due to MySQL internal design
Also usign a coverage index on the `head` table for `ID` and `CLOSING_DATE` better tune up the performaces

**DDLs AND RECORDS**

```sql
CREATE TABLE head (
  ID varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  CLOSING_DATE int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(ID),
  KEY CLOSING (ID, CLOSING_DATE)
);

CREATE TABLE `rows` (
  ID int NOT NULL,
  HEAD_ID varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRODUCT varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  QTY decimal(16,6) NOT NULL,
  STKQTY decimal(16,6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(ID),
  KEY PROD(PRODUCT),
  KEY HEAD(HEAD_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE production (
  ID int NOT NULL,
  ROW_ID int NOT NULL,
  QTY decimal(16,6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(ID),
  KEY ROWID(ROW_ID)
);

CREATE VIEW row_prod AS(
  SELECT ROW_ID, SUM(QTY) AS PRD_QTY FROM production WHERE ROW_ID <> 0 GROUP BY ROW_ID
);

CREATE VIEW stocking AS(
  SELECT 
    `rows`.PRODUCT,
    SUM(`rows`.STKQTY) AS STKQTY,
    GREATEST(SUM(CASE WHEN CLOSING_DATE <> 0 THEN 0 ELSE (`rows`.QTY - `rows`.STKQTY - COALESCE(row_prod.PRD_QTY, 0)) END), 0) AS RESQTY
  FROM
    `rows`
  INNER JOIN
    head ON head.ID = `rows`.HEAD_ID
  LEFT JOIN
    row_prod ON row_prod.ROW_ID = `rows`.ID
  GROUP BY
    `rows`.PRODUCT
);

INSERT INTO head (ID, CLOSING_DATE) VALUES 
 (1, 0),
 (2, 20220601),
 (3, 0);

INSERT INTO `rows` (ID, HEAD_ID, PRODUCT, QTY, STKQTY) VALUES 
 (1, 1, 'PROD_A', 10, 2),
 (2, 1, 'PROD_B',  5, 0),
 (3, 2, 'PROD_A', 15, 6),
 (4, 2, 'PROD_D',  7, 0),
 (5, 2, 'PROD_E', 12, 4),
 (6, 3, 'PROD_A',  3, 0),
 (7, 3, 'PROD_B',  1, 1),
 (8, 3, 'PROD_F',  5, 5),
 (9, 3, 'PROD_G',  6, 6);

INSERT INTO production (ID, ROW_ID, QTY) VALUES 
 (1, 1, 1),
 (2, 3, 6),
 (3, 4, 10);
```

**EXPLAIN DETAILS**

```
id|select_type|table     |partitions|type   |possible_keys   |key     |key_len|ref            |rows|filtered|Extra                                        |
--+-----------+----------+----------+-------+----------------+--------+-------+---------------+----+--------+---------------------------------------------+
 1|PRIMARY    |<derived2>|          |ALL    |                |        |       |               |   6|   100.0|                                             |
 2|DERIVED    |head      |          |index  |PRIMARY,CLOSING |CLOSING |96     |rows.HEAD_ID   |   3|   100.0|Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
 2|DERIVED    |rows      |          |ref    |HEAD,PROD       |HEAD    |92     |head.ID        |   1|   100.0|                                             |
 2|DERIVED    |<derived3>|          |ref    |                |        |4      |rows.ID        |   2|   100.0|                                             |
 3|DERIVED    |production|          |index  |ROWID           |ROWID   |4      |               |   3|   100.0|Using where                                  |
```

Comment: While having a Fiddle is immensely helpful, please nevertheless add your main query (as code) to your question. This way it might still be helpful when the link (for whatever reason) is no longer active.

Comment: Please update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN for when you query the view

Comment: @PM77-1 Thanks for the advice, I've edite the post by adding all the fiddle definitions and execution plan

Comment: Do you have indexes for the JOIN-ed columns - e.g. for HEAD_ID? Also note that VIEWs can not have their own indexes. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13945079/5962802